# C# Boolean Evaluation Not Evaluating As Expected

Tags: c#, boolean

I have a Visual Studio C# WinForms app in which a boolean must be evaluated to determine what the program will do next,

which is to either to throw a message box or do a function. The problem is that it does both when the boolean evaluates as

true.

Here's the code:

```
private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (QuestionNeedsSaving == true)
    {
        QuestionNeedsSaving = false;
        MessageBox.Show("You have made changes to this question." + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Click the Update Question button to " + "\r\n" + "Save changes or the changes will be lost.", "OOPS!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else if (QuestionNeedsSaving == false)
        GoToNextQuestion();
}
```

If the boolean "QuestionNeedsSaving" is true, then it gets set to false and throws a message box.
Otherwise, if "QuestionNeedsSaving" if false, then the function "GoToNextQuestion" is called.

The problem is that if "QuestionNeedsSaving" is true, both the message box AND "GoToNextQuestion" are executed.

"GoToNextQuestion" should only be executed if "QuestionNeedsSaving" is false to begin with.

Comment: Sounds like the method is getting called twice. Put a breakpoint down and step through it with visual studio.

Comment: The code is fine, bug ishould be in the part not shown here - i.e. double registration of button click.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the main problem is the constant state of QuestionNeedsSaving which is flase always through the if condition and better make the decision of QuestionNeedsSaving value in other place:

```
    private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (QuestionNeedsSaving == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have made changes to this question." + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Click the Update Question button to " + "\r\n" + "Save changes or the changes will be lost.", "OOPS!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else if (QuestionNeedsSaving == false)
            GoToNextQuestion();
    }
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: How it shouldn't matter and the declaration of QuestionNeedsSaving variable is out of scope of btnNextQuestion_Click and this means while program running the value after button click will be false and **still false when you click the button again** otherwise QuestionNeedsSaving changed its value in other location not mentioned here.

Comment: The QuestionNeedsSaving is a global variable. When a text box's TextChanged event fires, QuestionNeedsSaving is set to true, otherwise it is set to false. The problem is that both conditional statements in the code I posted above will fire regardless of whether QuestionNeedsSaving is true or false. Both blocks of code fire instead of just one block or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code and you will know that in case of odd button click QuestionNeedSaving=true which gives Next Question message but in case even button click QuestionNeedSaving=false which gives the OOPS! message and will be never the same.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace boolDecission
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    bool QuestionNeedsSaving = false;
    int x = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = x + 1;
        //even number will make QuestionNeedsSaving = false and odd            number will make QuestionNeedsSaving = true. 
        if (x % 2 == 1)
        {
            QuestionNeedsSaving = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            QuestionNeedsSaving = true;
        }
        if (QuestionNeedsSaving == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have made changes to this question." + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Click the Update Question button to " + "\r\n" + "Save changes or the changes will be lost.", "OOPS!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else if (QuestionNeedsSaving == false)
        {
            GoToNextQuestion();
        }
    }
    public void GoToNextQuestion()
       {
            MessageBox.Show("Next Question");
       }

    }
}
```